# Entity Framework | Propriedade double que permite null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Minha propriedade permite valores `double` e valores `null`. 
No Banco de Dados SQL Server ela está configurada como `decimal(18, 2)`.

Porém quando *seto* algum valor (ex: `5.00`), passa a dar o erro abaixo.

**Erro:**

> The 'Avaliacao' property on 'Ocorrencia' could not be set to a 'System.Decimal' value. You must set this property to a non-null value  of type 'System.Double'.

**Model:**

```
public class Ocorrencia
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double? Avaliacao { get; set; }
}
```

Como deve ficar para funcionar corretamente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer o cast para double

```
ocorrencia.Avaliacao = (double)5.00;
```

Comment: Não seria `ocorrencia.Avaliacao = (double)5.00;`?

Comment: Eu cometi este deslise e já corrigi rsrsrs

Answer (score 3):

Possivelmente você não está forçando a notação para `double`:

```
ocorrencia.Avaliacao = 5.00D;
```